# What spells can be cast while silenced?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've noticed that, while silenced, certain spells can still be cast, such as Divine Shield. What other spells can be cast while silenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only spells that grant spell (or total) immunity and have a mana (e.g. not rage, energy or focus) cost associated with them.

Examples are:

- Most Warrior, Hunter (and pet) and Rogue abilities (don't use mana as a resource)
- Divine shield, Ice Block (grant immunity), Dispersion
- All Totems *except Spirit Link*
- Barkskin, Aura Mastery
- Any zero-cost abilities, such as active racials, mounts (including paladin and warlock mounts) and items.

It is also worth baring in mind that silencing a Frost Mage will not prevent Water Elemental casts.

Comment: It depends on if the OP is talking about PVE or PVP interrupts/silences. Some warrior abilities cannot be cast while silenced. Such as Demoralizing shout cannot be cast. I'm not sure if you counter spelled a warrior (why?!) if they can still use all of their abilities, but in PVE some boss/mob silences stop a warrior from using similar abilities e.g. Demoralizing shout. Also be worth pointing out, interrupts are different to silences. With interrupts it halts that particular school of magic where as silence stops most magic abilities from all schools, minus immunity spells.

Comment: @Jared I think thunderclap is another ability affected by silence as well, although I've never paid much attention to warriors.

Comment: I know a Warrior's Throw can be interrupted. Can it be cast while silenced? Also, is Anti-Magic Shell one of the "grant immunity" moves that can be cast while silenced, or is it an exception?

Comment: All shouts (Demoralizing, Challenging, Battle, Commanding), Rallying Cry, Piercing Howl, Intimidating Shout, Taunt, and Thunder Clap are not usable while silenced. Shattering Throw can be interrupted, but being silenced does not prevent you from casting it.  So really, warriors get pretty gimped by being silenced.

Comment: I'll just leave it in community wiki mode. Feel free to update.